# Text HorzAlign doesn't work on runtime created Label

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

In an Android app, I'm trying to create a Label at runtime into a rectangle, and all of the properties works fine except for the Horizontal Align of the text. Is something wrong with my code?

```
procedure TForm7.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lb : TLabel;
begin
  lb := TLabel.Create(Rectangle1);
  lb.Parent := Rectangle1;
  lb.Align := TAlignLayout.Center;
  lb.TextSettings.HorzAlign := TTextAlign.Leading;
  lb.Width := 300;
  lb.TextSettings.Font.Size := 12;
  lb.StyledSettings:=[TStyledSetting.Family,TStyledSetting.Style,
    TStyledSetting.FontColor,TStyledSetting.Size,TStyledSetting.Other];
  lb.Margins.Bottom := 100;
  lb.Text := 'Programming Language is Delphi 10.4 31/3/2022';
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read up on [FMX.Graphics.ITextSettings](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Graphics.ITextSettings). You will find that there is an important relation between `TStyledSettings` and `TTextSettings`.

In your question you are concerned with horizontal alignment not following your setting:

> `lb.TextSettings.HorzAlign := TTextAlign.Leading;`

That is because you have overruled it by including `TStyledSetting.Other` in `lb.StyledSettings`.

Remove that `TStyledSetting.Other` from `lb.StyledSettings` and you will see that `HorzAlign`, `VertAlign`, `Trimming` and `WordWrap` will follow your own settings.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help you. The property `Alignment` of `TLabel` need to be configured to `taCenter`. But just it isn't enough. Beyond that, you need to configure property `AutoSize` to `false`. Then, everything will be OK.

```
lb.Alignment := taCenter;
lb.AutoSize := false;
```

---

The property `Align` isn't to align text inside label, but label component inside form. The `Alignment` is the correct property to align text inside label. Yes, I know, they could be clearer in coming up with these property names.